# Js Custom sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort array of strings `['d', 'CC', 'BB', 'b', 'a', 'Am','AMG']`
in such order `["AMG", "Am", "a", "BB", "b", "CC", "d"]`

Using

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});
```

I get `["a", "Am", "AMG", "b", "BB", "CC", "d"]`

Comment: because, a < am < amg < b < bb < cc < d - look in a dictionary ... the entry for `a` comes before the entry for `am`

Comment: your required order makes no sense

Comment: what is the rule behind?

Comment: First capital, than lower case

Comment: You're going to need something fancy then .. because localeCompare makes `a` < `A` and you want `a` > `A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain some sort criteria, after swapping the case of the letters, then

- sort by first lower case characters ascending,
- sort by length descending
- sort by string ascending

```js
function swap(s) {
    return Array.from(s, c => c.toUpperCase() === c ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase()).join('');
}

var array = ['d', 'CC', 'BB', 'b', 'bb', 'a', 'Am', 'AMG'];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = swap(a),
        bb = swap(b);

   return a[0].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[0].toLowerCase())
       || bb.length - aa.length
       || aa.localeCompare(bb);
});

console.log(array); // ["AMG", "Am", "a", "BB", "b", "CC", "d"]
```

Comment: if have ['bb', 'BB'] sort fails

["AMG", "Am", "a", "bb", "BB", "CC", "d"]